# What is an appropriate transformation of an age variable when used as a predictor of athletic performance?

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear

My question concerns using non-linear transformations on linear variables in regression, particularly where you believe the predictive weight might peak at some central value of the linear predictor.

The best example I can think of is Age with, say, 100m sprint times. You would probably believe that the times would shorten up to peak of about 27, and then gradually tail off again as the athlete gets older.

If you just enter Age as a predictor of sprint times without any transformation, you would likely miss out on a large amount of predictive value. So what are appropriate ways to transform the Age variable to reflect your belief about its areas of strongest predictive value?

The best idea I could so far come up with was subtracting the 'peak age' from the actual age and then squaring the outcome but I feel there is likely a better way.

For example (in R):

```
Age <- 8:70
PeakAge <- 27
TransAge <- (Age - PeakAge)^2
```

Any ideas on alternative methods would be much appreciated.

Comment: Something common in [polynomial curve fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression) is to first [standardize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score#Calculation_from_raw_score) (for better numerical properties) then fit a polynomial to the data (possibly with some regularization). (S

Comment: Your example transform appears to be "square of age distance from peak age", with squaring to make all values positive. I suspect that the squaring would distort the relationship, and that the effect (in this instance) would not be symmetrical around the peak value. You could take the square root of this square, similarly to how Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) is calculated with a square root - that would remove the distortion of squaring the relationship.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a spline, rather than any polynomial, because, while sprint time may well hit a minimum at approximately age 27, it is unlikely to be a very good fit to a quadratic, at least if you have a lot of ages.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Age <- 8:70
Age_squared = Age^2

lm(time~age+age_squared)
```

One nice feature is this approach allows you to get an estimate of the optimal age by differentiating the fitted quadratic, setting the derivative to zero, and solving for age.

Comment: Could you please describe how you would do that in a bit more details?